# Не рабоатет Threadpool в Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Не рабоатет Threadpool в Xamarin,как это можно пофиксить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.ThreadPool;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.System.Threading;
using task2;
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текст, а не картинку. Текст полностью должен индексироваться.

Comment: Видимо его не включили в состав, т.к. это слишком низкоуровневая работа с потоками. Используйте `Task` и `async/await` и не парьтесь.

Comment: ну я так и делаю,просто думал,почему не получается именно с этими работать)

Comment: `ThreadPool` - это класс, а не пространство имён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут следует оставить предположения и посмотреть спецификации xamarin. Если используете PCL/Profile, то там только async/await Task.
Решение Вашей проблемы в смене типа Core проекта с PCL на [.Net Standart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

После этого установить Nuget System.Threading.Thread и System.Threading.ThreadPool.

Общий совет/рекомендация - не работает с потоками(thread) если нет на то особой причины. Используйте задачи(Task)